How to get all channel messages with discord bot in javascript
I have the discord getting started example project running and working, so that I can run /test and it gives a working response. I also created a new command /getmessages, which now just returns a string.

I want to edit this command so it gets all messages sent in the channel, I've been trying to get this stackoverflow answer working:
Discord.js get an array of all messages in a channel
But I'm having trouble implementing the code from that stackoverflow accepted answer:
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("Your channel ID");
channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {
  console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`);
  //Iterate through the messages here with the variable "messages".
  messages.forEach(message => console.log(message.content))
})

If I try to add the first part, getting channel to my javascript code like so:
    if (name === 'getmessages') {
      // Get all messages from this channel
      console.log("try to get messages")

      try{
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get("961001859659759751");
      }catch(err){
        console.log("ERROR GETTING CHANNEL: ", err)
      }

      // Send a message into the channel where command was triggered from
      return res.send({
        type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
        data: {
          // Fetches a random emoji to send from a helper function
          content: '2. Hello we will try to get messages ' + getRandomEmoji(),
        },
      });
    }

I get this error:
ERROR GETTING CHANNEL:  ReferenceError: client is not defined

Is this the correct method I should use for trying to get every channel message using the discord example javascript bot as a starting off point? I'm not sure what the 'client' var would be since my app.js code is already communicating with discord and receiving/posting messages correctly.
My full app.js code:
import 'dotenv/config';
import express from 'express';
import {
  InteractionType,
  InteractionResponseType,
  InteractionResponseFlags,
  MessageComponentTypes,
  ButtonStyleTypes,
} from 'discord-interactions';
import { VerifyDiscordRequest, getRandomEmoji, DiscordRequest } from './utils.js';
import { getShuffledOptions, getResult } from './game.js';

// create client var
//export class Client<Ready extends boolean = boolean> extends BaseClient;

// Create an express app
const app = express();
// Get port, or default to 3000
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// Parse request body and verifies incoming requests using discord-interactions package
app.use(express.json({ verify: VerifyDiscordRequest(process.env.PUBLIC_KEY) }));

// Store for in-progress games. In production, you'd want to use a DB
const activeGames = {};

/**
 * Interactions endpoint URL where Discord will send HTTP requests
 */
app.post('/interactions', async function (req, res) {
  // Interaction type and data
  const { type, id, data } = req.body;

  /**
   * Handle verification requests
   */
  if (type === InteractionType.PING) {
    return res.send({ type: InteractionResponseType.PONG });
  }

  /**
   * Handle slash command requests
   * See https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#slash-commands
   */
  if (type === InteractionType.APPLICATION_COMMAND) {
    const { name } = data;

    // "getMessages" command
    if (name === 'getmessages') {
      // Get all messages from this channel
      console.log("try to get messages")

      try{
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get("961001859659759751");
      }catch(err){
        console.log("ERROR GETTING CHANNEL: ", err)
      }

      // Send a message into the channel where command was triggered from
      return res.send({
        type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
        data: {
          // Fetches a random emoji to send from a helper function
          content: '2. Hello we will try to get messages ' + getRandomEmoji(),
        },
      });
    }
    // "test" command
    if (name === 'test') {
      // Send a message into the channel where command was triggered from
      return res.send({
        type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
        data: {
          // Fetches a random emoji to send from a helper function
          content: 'hello world ' + getRandomEmoji(),
        },
      });
    }
    // "challenge" command
    if (name === 'challenge' && id) {
      const userId = req.body.member.user.id;
      // User's object choice
      const objectName = req.body.data.options[0].value;

      // Create active game using message ID as the game ID
      activeGames[id] = {
        id: userId,
        objectName,
      };

      return res.send({
        type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
        data: {
          // Fetches a random emoji to send from a helper function
          content: `Rock papers scissors challenge from <@${userId}>`,
          components: [
            {
              type: MessageComponentTypes.ACTION_ROW,
              components: [
                {
                  type: MessageComponentTypes.BUTTON,
                  // Append the game ID to use later on
                  custom_id: `accept_button_${req.body.id}`,
                  label: 'Accept',
                  style: ButtonStyleTypes.PRIMARY,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      });
    }
  }

  /**
   * Handle requests from interactive components
   * See https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#responding-to-a-component-interaction
   */
  if (type === InteractionType.MESSAGE_COMPONENT) {
    // custom_id set in payload when sending message component
    const componentId = data.custom_id;

    if (componentId.startsWith('accept_button_')) {
      // get the associated game ID
      const gameId = componentId.replace('accept_button_', '');
      // Delete message with token in request body
      const endpoint = `webhooks/${process.env.APP_ID}/${req.body.token}/messages/${req.body.message.id}`;
      try {
        await res.send({
          type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
          data: {
            content: 'What is your object of choice?',
            // Indicates it'll be an ephemeral message
            flags: InteractionResponseFlags.EPHEMERAL,
            components: [
              {
                type: MessageComponentTypes.ACTION_ROW,
                components: [
                  {
                    type: MessageComponentTypes.STRING_SELECT,
                    // Append game ID
                    custom_id: `select_choice_${gameId}`,
                    options: getShuffledOptions(),
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        });
        // Delete previous message
        await DiscordRequest(endpoint, { method: 'DELETE' });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error sending message:', err);
      }
    } else if (componentId.startsWith('select_choice_')) {
      // get the associated game ID
      const gameId = componentId.replace('select_choice_', '');

      if (activeGames[gameId]) {
        // Get user ID and object choice for responding user
        const userId = req.body.member.user.id;
        const objectName = data.values[0];
        // Calculate result from helper function
        const resultStr = getResult(activeGames[gameId], {
          id: userId,
          objectName,
        });

        // Remove game from storage
        delete activeGames[gameId];
        // Update message with token in request body
        const endpoint = `webhooks/${process.env.APP_ID}/${req.body.token}/messages/${req.body.message.id}`;

        try {
          // Send results
          await res.send({
            type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
            data: { content: resultStr },
          });
          // Update ephemeral message
          await DiscordRequest(endpoint, {
            method: 'PATCH',
            body: {
              content: 'Nice choice ' + getRandomEmoji(),
              components: [],
            },
          });
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Error sending message:', err);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port', PORT);
});


Are you defining a client variable? https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/main/Client:Class

@FrasherGray I edited my question to include my full app.js, at the moment i was not defining a client varaible, these docs look like they would have instructions on how to define it, but I tried adding the line export class Client<Ready extends boolean = boolean> extends BaseClient to my code, but it results in error about the "Ready" var being extended, how can I include that? is this the wrong way to define a client var?

The issue you are having is from how you are interacting with Discord. The example app repo you posted from Discord is using Express to make HTTP Requests to Discord's API.
However, the code you posted is trying to access Client, which is simply a variable, but in this context it's an instance of the Discord bot itself.
In simpler terms, your current setup involves direct calls to Discord's API but lacks a formal 'Client' setup.
I suggest this that you use Discord.js. Here's their guide. Discord.js is a very popular module for Discord, and it will save you a lot of time for re-inventing the wheel. There's also Discord bot frameworks built upon Discord.js.
